# jQuery UI Drag and Drop not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i'm making some experiments with Jquery UI draggable, but currently my application is not working and i don't understand why. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(".productItem").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    handle: "productItem"
});

$("#basket").droppable({
    accept: ".productItem",
    drop: function(event, ui){
        $("<div></div>")
            .html(ui.draggable.text())
            .appendTo($(this));
    }
});


</script>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Products</h2>
<div id="list">
<div class="productItem">product 1</div>
<div class="productItem">product 2</div>
<div class="productItem">product 3</div>
</div>

<hr/>

<h2>Basket</h2>
<div id="basket" style = "height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code is woring in JsFiddle, but i can't seem to make it work in chrome, so i think it is because of the jQuery include. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Change the version of jQuery UI to 1.8.23 and retest.

Comment: It doesn't work with 1.8.23...

Comment: Then it's the jQuery version. Anyhow you would prefer to use jQuery UI 1.8.23, it's pretty stable. Use it with jQuery 1.7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, the problem was i was using jQuery 1.8.0 which, didn't support jQuery UI, i changed to jQuery 1.7.2 and now it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your jQuery code inside a document ready block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".productItem").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        handle: "productItem"
    });
    $("#basket").droppable({
        accept: ".productItem",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $("<div></div>").html(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});​
</script>
```

The way you have it above, the code will try and execute before the relevant elements have even been loaded.

Comment: It still has a strange behaviour, not the drag and drop behaviour i was expecting.

Comment: What do you mean by "strange behavior"? Looks fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dA8wG/.

Comment: when i try to drag an element it creates a bunch of "<div class="productItem ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; ">product 1</div>" inside the list div. And i can't drag the element.

Comment: Do you have other scripts running on your page? Something else is causing your issue.

Comment: No, my code is the code i posted here with the "$(document).ready(function() {" bit.

Comment: Can you post a link to your page? As you can see by the fiddle, the code works so there must be something else going on.

Comment: It shouldn't be. You're calling the Google hosted jQuery files so unless they're not being loaded that shouldn't be an issue.